# Ajax function is not finding the right data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created an AJAX function and wondered why my JS was giving errors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#more').click(function() {
        var tag = $(this).data('tag'),
            maxid = $(this).data('maxid'),
            url = $(this).data('root'),
            id = $(this).data('id'),
            count = $(this).data('count');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ajax',
            data: {
                tag: tag,
                max_tag_id: maxid
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // Output data
                $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
                    $('section#images').append('<img src="' + data[src].images.standard_resolution.url + '">');
                });

                // Store new maxid
                $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have created a page that takes data from the instagram API and stores the data in an array so when I click more it loads more images into a container `div`.

**Edit:**

Below is the code on the php ajax page that encodes the array into json output:

```
  $instagram = new Instagram\Instagram;

  $instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['instagram_access_token']);
  $token = $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'];
    //$clientID = $_SESSION['client_id'];

  $current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();
  $tag = $instagram->getTag('folkclothing');

  $media = $tag->getMedia(isset($_GET['max_tag_id']) ? array( 'max_tag_id' => $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) : null);

  // Collect everything for json output
  $images = array();
  foreach ($media as $data) {
/*   $collection = array($data->images->standard_resolution->url,$data->link,$data->getId(),$data->likes->count); */
    /*
$images[] = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
    $images[] = $data->link;
    $images[] = $data->getId();
    $images[] = $data->likes->count;
*/
    /*
$data_url[] = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
    $data_link[] = $data->link;
    $data_id[] = $data->getId();
    $data_likes[] = $data->likes->count;
    $images[] = array($data_url);
*/
    $images[] = array($data->images->standard_resolution->url,$data->link,$data->getId(),$data->likes->count);
  }

  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->getNextMaxTagId(),
    'images'  => $images
  ));
```

The above code creates an array and then it gets converted to a json object but I am unsure how to split it into nested arrays for the image url, image id, likes and the image link. Is this possible to get nested arrays?

**End of edit**

It did work but I want to find specific elements inside this array so I created the AJAX function above.

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

Any help would be great.

Comment: The issue is the server side code, not the Javascript

Comment: try doing `console.log(data);` in the success function of ajax request, and tell us what you get in console

Comment: For the `success` function, do this: `success: function(data) {console.log(data);}`. Then you can go to the console and inspect the data to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: what is the json returned

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
               $('section#images').append(

               '<img src="' + data[src].images.standard_resolution.url + '">'

              );
          });
```

with

```
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
               $('section#images').append(

               '<img src="' + src.standard_resolution.url + '">'

              );
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to this I ended up building my array up properly and using the json_encode
to get it all listed properly so I could pull the right data out like so.

**ajax.php:**

```
  foreach ($media as $data) {
    $images[] = array(
        "data_url"=>$data->images->standard_resolution->url,
        "data_link"=>$data->link,
        "data_text"=>$data->getCaption(),
        "data_id"=>$data->getId(),
        "data_likes"=>$data->likes->count

    );
  }
  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->getNextMaxTagId(),
    'images'  => $images
  ));
```

This created the correct array of data.

I then corrected the js for it to work.

**JS code:**

```
$(".loading").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#more').click(function() {
        var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
            maxid = $(this).data('maxid');

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/ajax',
          data: {
            tag: tag,
            max_tag_id: maxid
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            // Output data
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
            var $content = $('<article class="instagram-image"><form class="forms" action="/image" method="post"><a class="fancybox" href="'+ data.images[i].data_link +'"><img alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" src="' + data.images[i].data_url + '" alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" /></a><button class="ajax instabtn like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+ data.images[i].data_id +'"><p>'+ data.images[i].data_likes +'</p></form></article>');
              $('section#images').append($content).fadeIn(1000);
              });
            // Store new maxid
            $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

I hope this helps people out who need that extra bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ....
 success: function(data) {
        // Output data
        $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
          $('section#images').append(
            '<img src="' + data[i].images.standard_resolution.url + '">'
                          //----^----here
          );
        });

        // Store new maxid
        $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
      }
```

Comment: then check you JSON...i think images is missing ther

Answer (score 0):

Change data access in image tag

from

```
data[src].images.standard_resolution.url
     ^^^
```

to

```
data[i].images.standard_resolution.url
     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `Array` of `data.images`, so you should use `index` of `data.images`

Try it like,

```
if(data.images)// check if data.images found, otherwise it will give error
{
    $.each(data.images, function(i, src){
       $('section#images').append(
          '<img src="' + data.images[i].standard_resolution.url + '">'
                        // use i ----^----here
                        // or use src.standard_resolution.url directly
       );
    });
}
```

Comment: This throws up Cannot read property 'standard_resolution' of undefined